# Using this with getelement

Tags: javascript

I have seen some code from a Google Chrome extension which calls `getElement` with this instead of document:

```
var item = this;
item.getElement('referrer').onclick = function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: item.referrer});
    return false;
};

item.getElement('by-ext').onclick = function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://extensions#' + item.byExtensionId});
    return false;
}
```

When I used a sample script in my browser like

`this.getElementById('anelement').innerHTML = 'something';`

it gives error and it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me why is it like this? Can the above method only be used with Google Chrome extensions?

Comment: You should have an exciting element with the id anelement

Comment: @hamism i just wanna know can this be used infront of getElementById('anelement').innerHTML ??.i get error when i added this before getelementbyid

Comment: what kind of error ? undefined or syntax error or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById` is defined only on `document`, not on any `HTMLElement` or anything else.
You could easily verify this by simply consulting the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById.

Note that this is different from `getElementsByClassName` etc., which can be invoked on any DOM element, and look below it for matches.

`this.getElementById` fails for the same reason that `this.boo` would fail--your `this` variable has no `getElementById` property/method defined on it (unless it's equal to `document`).

Comment: see i didnt get my output when i used this infront of getelement by id ..my question is in any situation can we add this infront of getelementbyid

Comment: Please read my answer again. Why do you care--just use `document.getElementById`? No, you can't use `this`, that's what my answer says. Why are you fixated on trying to use `this` to call `getElementById`? Curiosity? If you would take the time to learn how to open the console and see the output there, you would see a more informative error message about how `undefined is not a function` or something like that. That's becauuse it's trying to call `getElementById` which is `undefined`, because as I said **it's not on the object** which `this` is pointing to.

Comment: ..but i have seen the code which uses this before getelement by id in a chrome extension code..

Comment: `getElementbyId` and `getElement` are completely different. I don't even know what `getElement` is. If you want to get an element by its ID, then call `document.getElementById(elt_name)`, period, full stop. I have no idea what somebody else's code is doing with a method I have never heard of.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look what 'this' keyword is doing. Here is good documentation about java script this keyword https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

In this case 'this' is referring to the 'window' object.

Comment: i just wanna know can this be used infront of getElementById('anelement').innerHTML ??.i get error when i added this before getelementbyid –